# Defining classes in JavaScript that exist in your back-end

Tags: javascript, mvc, methodology, front-end

Doesn't it seem relatively duplicative to define your Models in your backend code AND on your front end for a rich internet application?

I'm porting a GUI application I had written to have a web interface, which is all grand and nice any all, but things like Spine, SproutCore, JavascriptMVC would have you define your models and views and implement specific controllers.

Being that I've got a well defined MVC pattern on my backend code (which is making this super easy to port; the views in my app took python dicts and returned python dicts to the controllers which could easy interface with the models; I can just convert these to JSON back and forth to speak to the web front end), why would I want to recreate the entire pattern again on the front end?

What are good ways to work around this?

Should I just say "screw this" and use something like http://pyjs.org?
Should I write a bunch of code to export my models into JSON and then write some JavaScript code to build the Models on the front-end automatically so I'm still only defining them once?

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: Just use node.js on the back end and power through with 100% code re-use.

Comment: I've already got my backend developed in Python. Also nodejs still doesn't provide a generic ORM module like SQLObject.  My data model is portable across ANY database that SQLObject supports without modification.  I like this model since I can start (or even do local dev) on SQLite and if I need better performance/functionality I can switch to a bigger DB system (mysql, postgres, etc) by changing a line in my configuration file.  And the app I'm building does not benefit from a NoSQL solution, so that's not the answer here.

Comment: there are various ORM tools that are good enough. The fact you can 'port' data between SQL databases is not an advantage. It means your using the dumb subset of all database and are simply just not using your database at all. I also dont see how running mysql or postgres locally is a problem. Unless your developing on a netbook

Comment: Why don't you develop your website with server-side Python? Developing sites entirely in JS doesn't have many advantages...

Comment: @Raynos "good enough" should never be acceptable. It's not that you're using the LCD functionality of the underlying DB, rather the ORM replicates functionality or relegates it to the database itself. With a real ORM there should be no disadvantages over using the ORM versus writing your own SQL queries; that's why you use a proper ORM. Plus if all else fails and the ORM can't cut it, you still can communicate via good old db-specific SQL via the ORM which will at least manage connection pooling, escaping queries, etc.  Also "your" would denote ownership. "you're" is what you wanted.

Comment: @alex, that's part of my question.  The back-end is entirely in JS.  Should I just say screw this HTML/JS thing and use Pyjamas? (It's Google Web Toolkit, but written in Python instead of Java).

Comment: @tkone this real ORM you described. I don't believe it exists.

Comment: @Raynos Show me something something that is commonly needed to be done in a database that isn't abstracted out by SQLObject, SQLAlchemy, the Django ORM, etc.  Regardless, who cares what color the bikeshed is (http://bikeshed.org/), this isn't the question I posed at all.

Comment: @tkone it's indeed massively off topic. The easiest code re-use strategy is having a DSL for your model and compiling it into both python and javascript.

Comment: With everything being so "scripty" already, can't you just use JSON to receive data from the Web backend, and have that automatically generate the domain object on the fly?  I can't tell from your question whether your architecture is going introduce a Web Server tier which will mediate between the Web client and your backend, or whether the new Web client will be running directly against your backend.

Comment: @SamGoldberg this is exactly what i ended up doing.  I've got a function that takes a SQLObject model (i'm using python) and converts it into a dict for passing into the JSON generator in python.  Then I use that to instantiate my models.  Turned out to be rather easy :)

Comment: @tkone: that's what I thought... felt good, didn't it? :)

Comment: I question your well designed MVC backend, if it was truly well designed adding a web based view would be trivial

Comment: @Ryathal i question your reading skill. This isn't about that at all -adding a web view is easy. The app is rife with them. What I'm talking about is that I've got a model definition in python using sqlobject. I want to do the front end in backbone/spine since its a web based app. Rather than a ton of server back and forths, it's all ajax and dom-editing. I need a model for backbone/spine. So now I'm writing my model twice, once in JavaScript and once in python. That violates the DRY principal. So what's the best way to configure the model on the front end so changes to the back end propagate

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question / problem, for me, knockout.js and their mapping plugin worked:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796909/is-there-a-native-way-to-create-client-side-models-to-post-to-my-controllers-wit

Comment: I didn't see this answer until just now. Will have to investigate. I do backbone for work now, so I'm inclined to use that, throw away my back end and just make a python rest client to communicate to a document store -- therefore the model is defined by the backbone model. It changes, cool, as old docs are loaded they'll change to the new format as well.